# Cron job not executing on Ubuntu 16 with DigitalOcean

Tags: php, cron

I've this cron task in my cron job table:

```
3 * * * * /usr/bin/php -zcf /var/www/html/assets/app/php/cron/adm_daily_backup.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This was working well on another server on Ubuntu 14 but not on my new server on Ubuntu 16.

When I'm calling manually the php script, the script works.

I already put in the php file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

How can I unblock me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you put the output of following commands?

Comment: which php     and     ls -l /var/www/html/assets/app/php/cron/adm_daily_backup.php

Comment: If you want to know why it's failing, then don't redirect its output and error streams to `/dev/null`

Comment: @kukulo, I'm using php 7.

Comment: @steeldriver, so I should change this to `/var/www/logs.txt` ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter where - as long as it's writeable

Comment: change your error redirect to: `>> ~/errlog.txt 2>&1`.  `/dev/null` goes to "bit bucket" (not what u want), > overwrites, >> appends

Comment: Please check the ownership of the backup php file. It should belong to www data owner. Otherwise it cannot be executed with proper permissions.